# Changing values in python array to a 1 or 0 depending on current value

Tags: python, arrays

Sorry, just updated this as realised I got the orders wrong.

I am new so advice is welcome.  I had a 1d array full of numbers from 0 to 5.

I need to go through it and if the number is 0, 1 or 4, I change it to 0. If the number is 2, 3 or 5, I need to change it to 1.

I know this sounds simply and I have tried many methods including: for, if, while but nothing works, it either has no effect or leaves them all as 1 or 0.

I am sure this is obvious to some but any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Something like `l = [x // 3 for x in l]`?

Comment: _"I have tried many methods"_: Show us what you tried! [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using list comprehension

```py
new_list = [0 if x in [0,1,4] else 1 for x in old_list]
```

Which is the same thing as

```py
new_list = []
for x in old_list:
    if x in [0,1,4]:
        new_list.append(0)
    else:
        new_list.append(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault.  Frenchytheasian answered the question then I changed it.  my mistake, not theirs!  Thank you

Comment: All good! It's a quick and easy change which I made to my answer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you frenchytheasian.  Works perfectly.  I was changing 0 to 1 then changing them all back to 1 .  Lesson learnt and all good!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can convert True and False to int to give you 1 and 0 respectively.

Therefore:

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newnums = [int(n in {2, 3, 5}) for n in nums]
print(newnums)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```